# How to obtain the value for the elements in structure which is also a vector inside a sturcture

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, structure

if I have a vector  inside another structure, how can I initiate or obtain the  value of an element insides the struct1

```
typedef struct_1 { 
      unsigned v1;
      unsigned v2;
      int v3;
    }struct1;

typedef struct_2{
      int v4;
      unsigned v5;
      vector <struct1> s1;
   } struct2;
```

Let's say to obtain v4, v5 I can do this:

```
struct2 *p = new struct2(); 
p->v4;
p->v5;
```

How do I access v1 and v2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you first need to "add" some elements into s1 vector, as by having a `struct2` object pointed by `p`, the `s1` vector is initialized to empty.

Comment: Thanks! how about let's assume there is some way to assign the data into s1 (e.g. through SQL API etc..)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the member by:

```
p->s1.at(index).v1;
p->s1.at(index).v2;
p->s1.at(index).v3;
```

Since initially this is empty, `at` will throw an exception. Alternatively, you can use `operator[]` but then you run into undefined behavior if the index is invalid.